Determine if file is zip or docx/xlsx based on only base64 string
Is there any way to determine if uploaded file is zip file or docx/xlsx file based on only base64 string  i specifying this since i do not have file extension.
I so far found solution which doing it using also file extension like this one
     private static readonly byte[] ZIP_DOCX = { 80, 75, 3, 4 };

     public static string GetMimeType(byte[] file, string fileName)
     {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName) == null
                           ? string.Empty
                           : Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpper();

         if (file.Take(4).SequenceEqual(ZIP_DOCX))
         {
            mime = extension == ".DOCX" ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/x-zip-compressed";
         }
      }

But as i said this solution is not working for me since i do not have extension of the file. Any ideas ?

There are certain file formats that have a specific "preamble" - that means a specific byte signature at the beginning of the file. If your desired formats do, too, you can use that. If it aligns with base64 chars, then it is especially easy.

Yes. You can extract the zip, look inside it, and see if the files correspond to an Excel or Word doc.

The problem is that any zip file signature header and  .docx  file signature is the same as far  as i understand

@Fildor docx and xlsx are both just zip archives though, so the file header will be that of a zip archive

I do not wanna extract the zip and check the file inside, if it is  real zip i wanna  throw ex, if it is .docx then continue

So there's a solution, but you don't want to do it? Why not? ZipArchive is a thing: you don't need to extract it to the filesystem or anything

aaa okay i g to you point maybe you can share the code in response  and i will accept as response

@canton7 Ah, snap. I was working with image formats, lately, so I wasn't immediately aware that that's the case. But it totally makes sense ... so some form of further introspection may be required ...

Aye, quite a bunch that share the header. Wikipedia lists "zip
aar
apk
docx
epub
ipa
jar
kmz
maff
msix
odp
ods
odt
pk3
pk4
pptx
usdz
vsdx
xlsx
xpi"

Sorry, I don't have time to work out what are the key differences between the contents of docx and xlsx files, and regurgitate the code from the MSDN pages on how to use ZipArchive. I'm sure with a little experimentation you can work it out

Sounded interesting so I played around with it. This isn't based on a spec so not super reliable. I just extracted one excel file and one word file and guessed at what the identifying characteristics might be. Seems to work.
public enum FileKind
{
    NotZip,
    OtherZip,
    Xlsx,
    Docx
}

public static class FileKindDecoder
{
    public static FileKind DetermineFileKind(string base64)
    {
        XElement? contentTypesXml;

        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var zip = OpenZip(stream))
        {
            if (zip == null)
                return FileKind.NotZip;

            var contentTypesEntry = zip.GetEntry(@"[Content_Types].xml");
            if (contentTypesEntry == null)
                return FileKind.OtherZip;
            contentTypesXml = ReadXmlFromZip(contentTypesEntry);
        }

        if (contentTypesXml == null)
            return FileKind.OtherZip;

        XNamespace ns = @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types";
        if (contentTypesXml.Name != ns + "Types")
            return FileKind.OtherZip;

        foreach (var overrideElement in contentTypesXml.Elements(ns + "Override"))
        {
            var contentType = overrideElement.Attribute("ContentType")?.Value;
            if (contentType == null)
                continue;
            if (contentType.Contains("spreadsheetml"))
                return FileKind.Xlsx;
            if (contentType.Contains("wordprocessingml"))
                return FileKind.Docx;
        }

        return FileKind.OtherZip;



        static ZipArchive? OpenZip(Stream stream)
        {
            try
            {
                return new ZipArchive(stream);
            }
            catch (InvalidDataException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        static XElement? ReadXmlFromZip(ZipArchiveEntry entry)
        {
            using var stream = entry.Open();
            try
            {
                return XElement.Load(stream);
            }
            catch (XmlException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}


Simplified approach which doesn't unzip any file or parse any XML.
public enum FileKind
{
    NotZip,
    OtherZip,
    Xlsx,
    Docx
}

public static class FileKindDecoder
{
    public static FileKind DetermineFileKind(string base64)
    {
        HashSet<string> containedFiles;

        try
        {
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            using var zip = new ZipArchive(stream);
            containedFiles = zip.Entries.Select(e => e.FullName).ToHashSet();
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException)
        {
            return FileKind.NotZip;
        }

        if (containedFiles.Contains("[Content_Types].xml"))
        {
            if (containedFiles.Contains("word/document.xml"))
                return FileKind.Docx;
            if (containedFiles.Contains("xl/workbook.xml"))
                return FileKind.Xlsx;
        }

        return FileKind.OtherZip;
    }
}


If the xl/workbook.xml or word/document.xml files always have to exist, it would probably be simpler, safer and faster to just check for their existence, but then a simple zip with that file in it would produce a false positive.

The way I skim through the [Content_Types].xml file is naive. I should probably take into account the  element as well, not just , but both MS Office and Google Docs use this style so it works in practice. I don't have LibreOffice et al to check how they do it.

Hi thanks for the  response, i will check it today and accept the response if everything went good

The over-engineered approach was bugging me overnight so I posted a simplified version. I don't know why I got obsessed with this.

Maybe you can also advice how to determine if base64 is .txt file or no ? I checked  couple of .txt files and all of them has different header signatures((

@So_oP .txt files don't have a header signature. You're just reading whatever the first few bytes of the text are

.txt is an extension, not a format. It's just raw characters from UTF8, ASCII or whichever other encoding, and the file got named .txt. Any text-based file format would also be a valid .txt if renamed: .xml, .py, .cs, .c, .csproj etc. The best you could do is check if the file contains only characters you consider acceptable for text, then try to eliminate all other formats you consider not txt. But there are always going to be examples which will cause mistakes. If you need file name extensions for whatever reason, you should probably store file names instead of guessing.

Ok another question then , i was able to get the type of .DOC file since the header is well known  byte[]  = { 208, 207, 17, 224, 161, 177, 26, 225 }, but when i tried to upload .XLS file it turned out that it also has the same signature. So is there a way to determine if file with signature byte[]  = { 208, 207, 17, 224, 161, 177, 26, 225 } is .DOC or .XLS , or any other types maybe also exist  with the same signature

I can create new question for this if you want

Should be a different question, yes. But personally, I have no idea. The old format was an old-school binary format, not a nice bunch of zipped XMLs, so it's more difficult to just open up and see.
